# Is there a way to define a HTML ID in vanilla Javascript without using a variable?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm extremely new to this so I apologise in advance if this is a dumb question or my definitions aren't quite correct.

What I'm trying to do is create a list of labeled boxes on a page which expand when you click on them, and the only way I've managed to get it working so far is below:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0v86ur4p/)

```js
var set = document.getElementById("setup")

function expand() {
    set.classList.toggle('contentclicked');
}
```

```css
.contentbutton {
    border-radius: 40px;
    background: #d6d6d6a1;
    padding: 20px; 
    width: 60%;
    height: 20px;  
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bolder;
    margin: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 7px #7979793d;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #79797967;
    -webkit-transition:0.5s;

  }

.contentclicked { 
  width: 90%;
  height: 200px;  

}
```

```html
<p class="contentbutton" id="setup" onclick="expand ()">SETUP</p>
```

I imagine there's a much cleaner way of doing that, but for now I'm just glad I got it working. However, to keep this up across the rest of the boxes, I'd have to define a variable for each box using their ID, then rewrite the function for each with that variable, which seems extremely inefficient and amateur.

Is there a way to remove the use of variables and just have it so that the Javascript knows which element has been clicked on and only runs the function on that? Or maybe the variable being something like this ("CURRENTELEMENT" being whatever element the function was called from):

```
var element = document.getElementByID('CURRENTELEMENT'),
```

CSS has built-in hover and active functions, so it's a shame it doesn't have an onclick function, but this seems like something that should be VERY easy to achieve with Javascript or one of its frameworks, and yet I'm struggling to find the answer. Even when I feel like I've found the answer using jQuery, I then don't understand how to call the specific function within the HTML element. I'm sure this is extremely easy but I'm struggling to find and grasp the answer.

Thanks in advance guys, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can be done easily with jquery by using a class instead of id, I am only mentioning jquery because the question is tagged with. https://api.jquery.com/on/. Can also be done with vanilla js, a bit more code is required but not hard

Comment: In the element: `onclick="expand(this);"` and the function: `function expand (ctx) {    ctx.classList.toggle('contentclicked');}`, no `set` variable needed.

Comment: Or use HTML that lets you do it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or use HTML that allows you to do it without any JavaScript

```css
.card > .toggle { display: none }
.card > .toggle + h3 + .contents {
  display: none;
}
.card > .toggle:checked + h3 + .contents {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" id="card_1"/>
  <h3><label for="card_1">Card Heading</label></h3>
  <div class="contents">
    <p>Card Contents</p>
    <p>Card Contents</p>
    <p>Card Contents</p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

If you want to add a class with JavaScript. Use a common class. Select it with query selector all and loop over the elements

```
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.contentbutton');
btns.forEach(function(btn){
  btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    btn.classList.toggle('contentclicked');
  });
});
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much! I threw the JS on that and worked like a dream. As I said, I'm very new to this so I appreciate the help no matter how stupid a question it may seem.

Answer (score 3):

Very easily :)

give to each element same class for example "contentbutton"
then to each of them add some event listener

```js
const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("contentbutton")

for(let i =0, len = buttons.length; i<len; i++){
  buttons[i].onclick = expand
}

function expand(e) {
  e.target.classList.toggle('contentclicked');
}
```

Comment: `getElementByClassName` should be `getElementsByClassName` - otherwise this will error out.

Comment: @AlexanderNied thanks for comment, typo is already corrected.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) on the class, and then just use the target on the event to add/remove classes to the clicked element.  Below is an implementation using an [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation) approach (so you only have a single listener on the `body`, rather than one listener for each element):

```js
function expand(e) {
  e.target.classList.toggle('contentclicked');
}

document.body.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  // event delegation
  if (e.target.classList.contains('expanding-btn')) {
    expand(e);
  };
});
```

```css
.contentbutton {
  border-radius: 40px;
  background: #d6d6d6a1;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 60%;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 7px #7979793d;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #79797967;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
}

.contentclicked {
  width: 90%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<p class="contentbutton expanding-btn">Ready</p>
<p class="contentbutton expanding-btn">Set</p>
<p class="contentbutton expanding-btn">Go</p>
```